# how to get value from one query and assign it to another one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in **mysql** database which are:

1. cars info
2. Images of car

Both of these table values are filled by a single form. In the Car table I have a field with the name of `'CarImageID'` which is a primary key with auto-increment and also in images table I have the same field `'CarImageID'` but FK with NOT UNIQE INDEX. what I want is whenever I pressed the submit button the second query gets its value from first query.  also I have created relationship Between them. HOW CAN I GET THE CarImageID FROM Imagequery AND USE IT IN MY SECOND QUERY WHICH IS CarInfoQuery?.

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');
    @$CarID=$_POST['CarID'];
    @$CarName=$_POST['pname'];
    @$CarModel=$_POST['pstatus'];
if(isset($_FILES['file_upload']))
{

$shuff=str_shuffle("ABD6565LSLFKDSAJFD");
mkdir("upload/$shuff");
$files=$_FILES['file_upload'];

for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++)
{
  $name=$files['name'][$x];
  $tmp_name=$files['tmp_name'][$x];
     if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/$shuff/".$name))
     {
      $imagequery="INSERT INTO CarImages(CarImageID, ImageName, ImagePath) 

      VALUES(‘ ’, '$name', 'upload/$name')";

      mysql_query($imagequery);

            echo 'Image '. $name .' Uploaded Successfully <br>';

     }
     else
     {
         echo 'uploading failed';
     }

}
$carinfoquery="INSERT INTO Car(CarID, CarName, CarModel, CarImageID)

         VALUES('// this value should take its value from first query', '$CarName', '$CarModel', 'CarImageID')";

          mysql_query($carinfoquery)  or die(mysql_error());

          if($carinfoquery)
          {
              echo '<br><br> The Car Information Insertion was 
                              Successfully <br><br>';
          }
          else
          {
              echo '<br><br> Car Insertion Failed';
          }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
  mysql_query($imagequery);
  $carimageid = mysql_insert_id();
```

or to be safe, use the mysql_query resource:

```
$res = mysql_query($imagequery);
$carimageid = mysql_insert_id($res);
```

The second way is usefull if you have multiple querys and don't want to run into the chance to mix them up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mysql functions use mysqli

if you use mysqli use

```
$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

In current function You can use

```
$res = mysql_query($imagequery);
$id = mysql_insert_id($res);
```

Use this id to insert in next query.

Comment: i changed back the mysqli to mysql the other errors removed except this one 'Warning: mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:'

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a query before the `second insert query` to retrieve **last entry ID** because you don't indicate it in first query and just let database handle it on the base of last entry (this is because it is an autoincrement field)

**so change**

```
 mysql_query($imagequery);
```

**in**

```
 $lastid = mysql_query($imagequery);
 $last_entry_id = mysql_insert_id($lastid);
```

now you have your variable stored in `last_entry_id` and you can use in second query

I would like to also to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for new projects.

Comment: i receives this error massage : 'Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PropertyImages\index.php on line 20'

Comment: this is because you are not using `mysqli` as connection but `mysql_` please copy and paste direcly, i didn't use `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

get insert id

```
$res = mysql_query($imagequery);
$carimageid = mysql_insert_id();
```

if db col CarImageID value is $carimageid  then

```
$carinfoquery="INSERT INTO Car(CarID, CarName, CarModel, CarImageID)

         VALUES('// this is CarID if col is auto_increment ,blank this', '$CarName', '$CarModel', '$carimageid')";
```

then use if($run_query) not if($carinfoquery)

```
     $run_query =  mysql_query($carinfoquery)  or die(mysql_error());

          if($run_query)
          {
              echo '<br><br> The Car Information Insertion was 
                              Successfully <br><br>';
          }
          else
          {
              echo '<br><br> Car Insertion Failed';
          }
```

update
table structure may be

```
Car(CarID, CarName, CarModel)
CarImages(CarImageID, ImageName, ImagePath,CarID)
```

Comment: i changed back the mysqli to mysql the other errors removed except this one 'Warning: mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert at `CarImageID`, because it is Auto-increment column.
If you got `Warning: mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean...`
it means your `INSERT` statement failed , so use `die(mysql_error()` to find the problem.

```
$imagequery="INSERT INTO CarImages(ImageName, ImagePath) VALUES('$name', 'upload/$name')";
mysql_query($imagequery) or die(mysql_error());
$id = mysql_insert_id($res);
```

EDIT 1:

I think your table structure have problems. A car may have multiple images. So table structures should be like this:
`Car(CarID, CarName, CarModel)` which `CarID` is PK and auto-increment. `CarImages(CarID, CarImageID, ImageName, ImagePath)` which `CarID` is FK and `CarImageID` is auto-increment.
You should first INSERT into `CAR` table, then get `CarID` with `mysql_insert_id()` and use this id for INSERT into `CarImages` table.

Comment: ya you were right but gives this error massage : 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`propertyimage`.`propertyimages`, CONSTRAINT `propertyimages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PropertyImageID`) REFERENCES `properties` (`PropertyImageID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)'

Comment: i have two tables one is properties and sec one is poperties images

Comment: I see, You should INSERT to table `car` and then to `carimages` table. you did vice versa.